# Netlify. How to build locally and deploy bundle to prod

Tags: netlify, netlify-cli

Is it possible to build locally and deploy a bundle to Netlify?

Answer (score 0):

Yes,

You can drag a project folder to the deploy zone, I believe it will create new site.

[Here is the link to the Docs](https://docs.netlify.com/site-deploys/create-deploys/#drag-and-drop) even has a video example.